# can ayone what is happening at the background

Tags: java, thread-synchronization

```
package workouts;

public class synchro {

    private int count = 0;

    public void counting() {

        Thread T1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

                    count++;
                }
            }
        });

        Thread T2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

                    count++;
                }
            }
        });

        T1.start();
        T2.start();

        try {
            T1.join();
            T2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("counting =" + count);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        synchro sync = new synchro();

        sync.counting();
    }
}
```

but when introduced a synchronised method and call it inside run method like below.. the output is 20000 for how many times if u run it..can someone explain the difference between the above and below code

```
public class synchro {

    private int count = 0;

    public synchronized void dosinglethread(){
        count++;
    }

    public void counting() {

        Thread T1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    dosinglethread();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread T2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

                    dosinglethread();
                }
            }
        });

        T1.start();
        T2.start();

        try {
            T1.join();
            T2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("counting =" + count);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        synchro sync = new synchro();

        sync.counting();
    }
}
```

Comment: why volatile keyword didnt work on the variable ??

Comment: with such trivial threads, the first one would probably finish before the second one has started up.

Comment: @sritharan I don't really see where did you use `volatile` in your code...

Comment: I assume he meant making the line "private volatile int count = 0;" in the op of the first example. This does not help ensure the proper count. The question is why? The answer is provided by DennisW -- the variable count may be volatile, the one needs the entire operation (fetch, increment, assign) to be synchronize, not just the variable.

Comment: @alfasin
i ment that
if we use  
private volatile int count = 0;
instead of using 
public synchronized void dosinglethread(){
        count++;
    }

Answer (score 1):

When you say `count++`, three things happen:

1. The current value of `count` is retrieved by the VM
2. The VM increments the value by 1
3. The new value is put back into `count`

It's entirely possible that T1 and T2 both get the value of `count`, then increment it separately, and then but back the result, like so:

```
Timeslot    T1                    T2
1           count = 3             ----
2           ----                 count = 3
3           3 + 1 = 4            ----
4           ----                 3 + 1 = 4
5           store 4 in count     ----
6           ----                 store 4 in count
```

So now, `count++` has been called twice, but the value has only increased by one. To prevent this, you have to make the increment *atomic*. Atomic means that either the entire sequence of operations is executed, or none of it is. Simply put, if two statements are `synchronized` on the same `Object`, they will not interleave.

In your second piece of code, `dosinglethread()` is declared `synchronized`. This is the equivalent of:

```
public void dosinglethread() {
    synchronized (this) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

This means that when one of the threads starts executing it, they acquire a *lock* on your `synchro` instance. When the second thread also tries to execute the method, it will see that another thread already owns the lock on `this`, so it has to wait. When the first thread completes the method, it will release the lock and the other thread can then take it.

So why didn't `volatile` work? `volatile` variables will not cause threads to wait until they are available. Instead, when `count` is `volatile` and you call `count++`, the following happens: (Code adapted from [Javamex's Tutorial](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile_dangers.shtml))

```
int temp;
synchronized (count) {
  temp = count;
}
temp = temp + 1;
synchronized (count) {
  count = temp;
}
```

*Note that this code is for illustration only: `synchronized` can not be used on primitives.*

It's clear, then, that the threads might still be paused at `temp = temp + 1`, giving the same problems as when you don't do any synchronization.

For more information, check [the tutorial I mentioned.](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml)